# Как при выборе checkbox добавить class его label?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте.
При выборе нужного checkbox присваивается класс сразу всем label, а нужно только выбираемому. При повторном нажатии класс не удаляется.
При любом выборе показывается блок `.block-all`, но  вот при повторном нажатии на checkbox (чтобы закрыть все блоки), этот блок не закрывается.
Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибки. Спасибо!

```js
$("#block-box input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
  $(".blocks").hide();
  $("#block-box input[type='checkbox']").not(this).each(function(){
    $("#block-box label").removeClass("label_active");
    $(".block-all").hide();
    this.checked = false;  
  });
  if (this.checked)
    $("." + $(this).data("blockclass")).show();
    $("#block-box label").addClass("label_active");
    $(".block-all").show();
});
```

```css
.block-ru,
.block-ua,
.block-all {
display: none;
}
.label_active {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block-box">
<label class="label_ru"><input type="checkbox" name="ru" id="ru" value="1" data-blockclass="block-ru">Россия</label>
<label class="label_ua"><input type="checkbox" name="ua" id="ua" value="1" data-blockclass="block-ua">Украина</label>
</div>
<div class="blocks block-ru">Выбор России</div>
<div class="blocks block-ua">Выбор Украины</div>
<div class="blocks block-all">Показ при любом выборе</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#block-box input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
  // hide and deactivate everything
  $(".blocks").hide();
  $(".block-all").hide();
  $("#block-box label").removeClass("label_active");
  // uncheck all other checkboxes
  $("#block-box input[type='checkbox']").not(this).each(function(){
    this.checked = false;  
  });
  // show/activate things for this checkbox, if it is checked
  if (this.checked) {
    $("." + $(this).data("blockclass")).show();
    $(this).closest("label").addClass("label_active");
    $(".block-all").show();
  }
});
```

```css
.block-ru,
.block-ua,
.block-all {
display: none;
}
.label_active {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block-box">
<label class="label_ru"><input type="checkbox" name="ru" id="ru" value="1" data-blockclass="block-ru">Россия</label>
<label class="label_ua"><input type="checkbox" name="ua" id="ua" value="1" data-blockclass="block-ua">Украина</label>
</div>
<div class="blocks block-ru">Выбор России</div>
<div class="blocks block-ua">Выбор Украины</div>
<div class="blocks block-all">Показ при любом выборе</div>
```